# MongoDB: Best way query users by given names and username

Tags: mongodb, search

I'm trying to implement a user search that looks into the user's given names and their username, while also being able to sort results by relevance.

I tried creating a text index like this

```
db.users.createIndex({
    username: 'text',
    firstName: 'text',
    lastName: 'text'
},
{
    name: 'text_search',
    default_language: 'en',
    language_override: 'language'
})
```

But this doesn't take into account partial terms, so if I search for "Juan F", I get the following results

```
{ score: 3.7, username: "juanjo", firstName: "Juan", lastName: "Rivas F" },
{ score: 2.95, username: "Juan.rodriguez", firstName: "Juan", lastName: "Rodriguez" },
{...} // 6 more
{ score: 2.2, lastName: "Fuentes", firstName: "Juan", username: "juanfuentes" }
```

I understand that text indexes take into account similar words, but not partial terms, so with "Juan Fuente" I get the desired result, with "Juan F", "Juan Fu", etc, I don't.

Is there a way to improve this, in order to be able to implement a search that returns results as the user types into a search box?

**Edit** This is the query I tried:

```
db.users.find(
    { $text: { $search: "juan f" } },
    { score: { $meta: "textScore" } }
).sort({ score: { $meta: "textScore" } })
```

Comment: On what field you are searching? Is it username?

Comment: The text search uses all fields specified when creating the index. I updated the question.